# Convergence in distribution of the maximum of a sequence of random variables

Tags: mathematical-statistics, extreme-value

How to find the following:

Let $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$,..., $X_n$, be i.i.d with chi-square distribution with one-degree of freedom. Find $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $ a_n(\max_i X_i - b_n)$ converges in distribution to a nondegenerate random variable.

I thought about Central limit theorem but I don't think it is the useful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Central Limit Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Central_limit_theorems_for_independent_sequences) won't be useful here since  the random variable of interest $M_n := \max (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ is not the sum/average of a series of random variables but rather their maximum.

The study of the maximum of a sequence of random variables is part of [extreme value theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theory). The cornerstone result is the Extremal Types Theorem (also known as [Fisher-Tippett-Gnedenko theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Tippett%E2%80%93Gnedenko_theorem)) which provides the three possible non-degenerate limit distribution (note the slightly different role of $a_n$ compared to your notation). These three distribution are grouped in the [Generalized extreme value (GEV)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_extreme_value_distribution) distribution.
So, the Extremal Types Theorem is essentially the analogous of the Central Limit Theorem for maxima, where the non-degenerate limit, if it exists, is the GEV distribution.

One way to find the normalising sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ is to use the sufficient (but not necessary) von Mises conditions.

Let $F$ denote the distribution function of $X_i, i=1, \ldots, n$. For a sufficiently smooth distribution $F$ with upper terminal $x_F = \sup\{ x : F(x) < 1 \}$ , define the reciprocal hazard function as
$$
r(x) = \frac{1-F(x)}{f(x)} ,
$$
where $f$ denotes the density function.
Then, with $b_n = F^{-1}(1 - 1/n)$, $a_n = r(b_n)$, and $\xi = \lim_{x\to x_F} r'(x)$
the distribution of $(M_n - b_n)/a_n$ is GEV with shape parameter $\xi$.

The von Mises condition could be used to find the sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ but computations for the $\chi_1^2$ distribution might be painful.

Comment: Thank you for the information. To clarify what does $F^{-1}$ stand for? Inverse or $1/F(x)$ ?

Comment: The notation $F^{-1}(x)$ denotes the inverse of $F(x)$.